# Firebase image download from storage failed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I believe my implementation is wrong but i can't get my head around it.
I have searched for tutorials but can't find, It's only the official documentation i can find which is too much detailed for me to understand :)

```
 //initialize
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    // Points to the root reference
    StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://nse-ninja.appspot.com");

    // Create a child reference

    // imagesRef now points to "images"
    StorageReference imagesRef = storageRef.child("images");
    StorageReference spaceRef = storageRef.child("images/games.png");

    File localFile = null;
    try {
        localFile = File.createTempFile("games", "png");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    spaceRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to download", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

After running the failed toast keeps popping up

Here is logcat

```
 E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
                                                 User does not have permission to access this object.
                                                  Code: -13021 HttpResult: 403
```

Comment: Can you post here thrown error please?

Comment: Add a log statement like this to `onFailure()` to see what the error is: `Log.d(TAG, "Download Failed: " + exception.getMessage());`

Comment: What is firebase guys. Just wanted to have some basic knowledge ?

Comment: @PřemyslŠťastný I've updated with logcat

Comment: @qbix I've updated with logcat

Comment: You need to use the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/) to update the [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/) for your storage.

Answer (score 2):

This is likely because your [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security) don't allow access. You can change your rules "public" by using the following rules:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/nse-ninja.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Read [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start) for some more info!